# Borelians of $[-\infty,\infty]^D$

Tags: measure-theory

It is known that the family of sets $\{\prod_{i=1}^D[a_i,\infty]\}$ where $a_i\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{-\infty\}$ generates the borelian $\sigma$-algebra of $[-\infty,\infty]^D$.

> How do I prove that the family of sets $\{\prod_{i=1}^D(a_i,\infty]\}$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{-\infty\}$ also generates the borelian $\sigma$-algebra of $[-\infty,\infty]^D$? Is it even true?

My approach was trying to write every set of the family $\{\prod_{i=1}^D[a_i,\infty]\}$ as an intersection of sets of the other family. But this trick is only valid for sets with every $a_i>-\infty$.

**Update**: I asked the same question in MathOverflow, and they suggest me that the result is a consequence of the following theorem

> $\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty]^D)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^D\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty])$

I was aware of that result. In fact, I know that

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty]^D)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^D\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty])=\sigma\left(\left\{\prod_{i=1}^D: C_i\in\mathcal{C}_i\text{, }\sigma(\mathcal{C}_i)=\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty])\text{, }[-\infty,\infty]\in\mathcal{C}_i\right\}\right)\text{. }
\end{equation}
However, I can't see why my question is a consequence of this.

Comment: Does $\oplus$ mean $\cup$ here?

Comment: Yes, it just emphasizes that the union os disjoint